# adding a hover on image without affecting the border

Tags: css, hover, border

i have an image and a border around it i want to add blur hover to the image only but the blur covers the image and the border here's the code

```css
.ex{
    border-radius: 1000px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    overflow: hidden
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;

    
}
.ex:hover{
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    cursor:pointer;
```

```html
<img src="img/13.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200" class="ex">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the image in a parent element, then that element to create the circle border, and give it a positive `z-index` so the image doesn't pop out when you apply `filter`.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap {
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.ex {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.wrap:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrap:hover .ex {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://scontent-dft4-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/17266233_1741922516118154_2155597975093510144_n.jpg" alt="" class="ex">
</div>
```

Comment: @majidmashmool which browser are you using? I'm not seeing it in firefox or chrome

Comment: sorry it was my mistake i put 2 period for the css code

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image with a **div**, set the **div** size and **overflow:hidden** and you archive that.

```
.img-wrapper-for-blur {
        border-radius: 1000px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

removing **border-radius** from your **.ex** style and the markup changed by this:

```
<div class="img-wrapper-for-blur">
    <img src="img/13.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200" class="ex">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a border, you can wrap the image in a `div`, give that `div` some padding and a white background, and then leave the blur on the image.

HTML

```
<div class="border">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt="" width="200" height="200" class="ex">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ex {
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.ex:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.border {
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fm1hLy6h/